# How to customize "Return" link in Laravel Spark?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I'm using Laravel Spark (not classic, v11) to scaffold out my newest SaaS application. Everything is going well, but the only thing I'm not able to customize is the "Return to [Application Link]" once users are actually in the billing portal.

Right now, it defaults to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), which returns users to my home page. Instead, I'd like it to return users to [www.example.com/dashboard](http://www.example.com/dashboard).

I've read every page of the documentation thoroughly, but don't see any sort of default customization built in for this.

I'm using Spark-Stripe (as opposed to Spark-Paddle) if it makes a difference, though I don't think it would.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That URL should default to `/dashboard`, but you can customize it by adding this line to your spark.php config file:

`'dashboard_url' => '/dashboard',`

For more details on how Spark is using this config value, see these files:

```
../vendor/laravel/spark-stripe/src/FrontendState.php
../vendor/laravel/spark-stripe/resources/js/Pages/BillingPortal.vue
```

Comment: Thank you kind stranger! This is exactly what I needed. I'm surprised this wasn't included in the documentation. Thank you very very much.